# Need Regex for a text box so that it accepts first letter a character and remaining as digits

Tags: c#, regex, winforms

Hi all i need a `regex` that accepts first letter as character and the remaining should be digits.

Even spacing is not allowed too..

```
Possible cases : a123, abc123, xyz123 and so on ...
Unacceptable : 123abc,1abc12, a 123 and so on..
```

i tried some think like this but i am not sure this works so can any one help me..

```
"[A-Z][a-z]\d{0,9}"
```

Answer (score 2):

```
^[A-Za-z]+[0-9]+$
```

matches one or more ASCII letters, followed by one or more ASCII digits. If digits are optional, use `[0-9]*` instead.

If you want to also allow other letters/digits than just ASCII, use

```
^\p{L}+\p{D}+$
```

Answer (score 1):

you probably need this:

```
"[a-zA-Z]+\d+"
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this expression   `[A-Za-z]\w*`

Answer (score 0):

`[A-Z]|[a-z]{1,}\d{1,}`

But as you mentioned, possible cases should be: a123, b321, z4213213, but not abc123. Right?

So regExp shoud be `[A-Z]|[a-z]\d{1,}` .

Comment: You could just have the grouping as [A-Za-z] rather than adding the | part.

Answer (score 0):

I would highly recommend you do not limit yourself to ASCII as most of the other answers for this question do.

Using [character classes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/20bw873z%28v=VS.71%29.aspx), which I recommend, you should use:

```
^[\p{Ll}\p{Lu}\p{Lt}\p{Lo}\p{Pc}]\d+$
```

See [the reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h5181w5w%28v=VS.71%29.aspx) for `^` and `$`.